# Cannot draw my model twice in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw a model of a chair that I exported from 3ds max as a txt file. I read the file and display it in OpenGL (using Visual Studio -> C++). My problem is that I have to multiplicate the chair many times (10). I did try to multiplicate it twice but it does not work. The program crashes with these "Program is not responding" Windows errors. I have a main class that calls all of the nessessery methods from CDrawModel like that:

```
CDrawModel  mModel;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize( 1000, 600 );
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Georgi Koemdzhiev - 1306794");

glutKeyboardFunc(KeyResponse);

glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene);
glutReshapeFunc(ReSizeGLScene);

mModel.initGL();

glutMainLoop();
}

void DrawGLScene(void) {
   mModel.myDrawGLScene();
}


GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei fwidth, GLsizei fheight) {
   mModel.MyReSizeGLScene(fwidth, fheight);
}
```

CDrawModal initialises an object of type CPolygonMesh which handles the reading from the file and drawing on the screen functionality. I know my code works since I am getting my modal drawn on the screen:
[image]

this is my CDrawModal class:

```
oid CDrawModel::initGL(void) {
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

near = 1.0;
far = 1000.0;
height = 1.5;


glCullFace(GL_BACK);            // don’t draw back facing faces
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);         // enable face culling
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);   // select front polygons and draw edges only



}




 void CDrawModel::MyReSizeGLScene(int fwidth, int fheight) // Resize And             Initialize The GL Window{  


// Store window size so it can be accessed in myDrawGLScene()
wWidth = fwidth;
wHeight = fheight;

//  Set fovy so that the viewing frustum has the specified height at the 
//  near clipping plane
fovy = (360 / PI) * atan(height / (2.0 * near));

//  Calculate the aspect ratio of the VIEWPORT
//  so that we can set the camera’s aspect ratio to the same value
aspect_ratio = (double)fwidth / (double)fheight;


glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                    // Select The Projection Stack
glLoadIdentity();
/*  void glOrtho(   GLdouble left,
GLdouble right,
GLdouble bottom,
GLdouble top,
GLdouble nearVal,


GLdouble farVal);*/
gluPerspective(90, aspect_ratio, near, far);  // perspective view
//glOrtho(-130.0,130.0,-130.0,130.0,near,far);

glViewport(0, 0, wWidth, wHeight);              // Viewport fills the window


// Print values of parameters   
cout << fixed;      // Use fixed-point notation
cout.precision(3);  // Number of digits after the decimal point

cout << "fovy = " << fovy << endl;
cout << "aspect_ratio = " << aspect_ratio << endl;
cout << "near = " << near << endl;
cout << "far = " << far << endl;

}

void CDrawModel::myDrawGLScene(GLvoid)      // Here's Where We Do All The    Drawing
  {
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    // clear the drawing area
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();

 glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -200);
 mesh.draw_model();


glutSwapBuffers(); // Needed if we're running an animation
glFlush();

}
```

What I need to do in order to draw it twice.This is my drawModal method in  CPolugonMesh:

```
 void CPolygonMesh::draw_model(void){
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
 glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // draw red things

 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                 
    for (int i = 0; i < Mesh_NumFaces; i++) {       
        // Look up the coordinates of each vertex
        // in vertex_list[] 
        glVertex3fv(vertex_list[ face_list[i][0] ]);
        glVertex3fv(vertex_list[ face_list[i][1] ]);
        glVertex3fv(vertex_list[ face_list[i][2] ]);

        //cout << "Drawing face: " << i << endl;
    }

 glEnd(); 

 }
```

Comment: So what exactly did you try? Chucking in an extra e.g.  `glTranslatef(20.0, 0.0, 0.0); mesh.draw_model();` after the existing call?

Comment: I tried to basically copy those 2 lines of code but translate the new mesh.draw_model() to the right a bit. However, there was only one object on the screen, still. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CPolygonMesh::draw_model(void)` method actually *clears the screen* each time you draw a model, so only the last call will leave anything on the screen.

The line

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

is totally wrong there. You already do clear the screen at the beginning of your frame.

Comment: You have no idea how much time you just saved me! That fixed my problem, thank you very much!